# Chromecast with JW Player on iOS mobile browser

Tags: ios, html, google-chrome, chromecast, jwplayer6

I've been trying to get Chromecasting to work with JW Player on iOS Chrome. For what ever reason, the icon for it does not show up. It works on Android devices. Originally I was using 7.3.4 but rolled back to 6.12. My setup is this:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "http://server/master.m3u8",
    provider: "hls",
    androidhls: true, 
    primary: "flash", 
    aspectratio:"16:9", 
    cast:{
        appid:"ABCD1234",
    },
});
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like the new iOS version of Chrome no longer supports Chromecast. I have my own HTML5 video player with Chromecast implementation that is broken under iOS.

May be this is related [A faster, more stable Chrome on iOS](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/01/a-faster-more-stable-chrome-on-ios.html)